# TizenOS Freeze Function

Tags: tizen

I need a TizenOS-App that freezes the picture for video from Hdmi or Airplay. Should be activated via Letter-Buttons on Remote.  Known from projectors.

I tried:

```
var blankScreen = function() {
    webapis.avplay.setDisplayRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
};

var freezeScreen = function() {
    webapis.avplay.setDisplayMethod("PLAYER_DISPLAY_METHOD_FREEZE");
};
```

Comment: Would you check the parameter type of setDisplayMethod()? current code is using invalid parameter. refer to this page : https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/avplay-api.html